# Style to get the Listbox Bottom Border in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a Listbox in my slverlight Application. I have applied the Background color to the Listbox Item. So NOW I need Bottom horizontal line to separate the Listbox Items. 
I have mentioned the style everything works fine accept the Bottom Border is not displaying.

Style :-

```
<Style x:Key="ItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BaseColorBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF333333"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,2,2"/>
</Style>
```

Could you please help me get the Bottom border for Listbox Item.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<UserControl.Resources> 
    <Style y:Key="ListBoxItemStyle2" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="TabNavigation" Value="Local"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup y:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState y:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState y:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".35" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState y:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup y:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState y:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState y:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup y:Name="FocusStates">
                                <VisualState y:Name="Focused">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState y:Name="Unfocused"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle y:Name="fillColor" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                        <Rectangle y:Name="fillColor2" Fill="#FFBADDE9" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1"/>
                        <ContentPresenter y:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                        <Rectangle y:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Stroke="#FF6DBDD1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid y:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White"    >        
    <ListBox Height="146"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="236,49,0,0"
                y:Name="listBox1"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="120"
                **ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle2}"**>    
        <ListBoxItem Content="Australia" />
        <ListBoxItem Content="Canada" />
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I have already defined the dataTemplate for the listbox. Because my Listbox Item is one Usercontrol. so i cannot define Template inside the Style.